# Good IDE or syntax highlighting editor for Mason?

Tags: perl, ide, editor, mason

Can anyone recommend some good IDEs or editors for Mason?

At this point I'm just using VIM but it would be nice to have an editor that supports syntax highlighting as well as general syntax checking.

There are plenty that support Perl of course, but when it comes to files with Mason and Perl intertwined the editors tend to get confused and highlight incorrectly.

Comment: Are you using any customized highlighting for Mason in vim?

Comment: Yep, but it doesn't do syntax checking, only highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Komodo IDEs](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) (ver. 4 to 6) have Mason-support and
can handle Mason and HTML in the same document.
I wouldn't be suprised if the Komodo-Edit
has that also.

[Komodo-Changelog-29642](http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Komodo-Changelog-29642.html):

> What's new in Komodo 4.0.3:
>
> New languages: Support for Template-Toolkit, **HTML-Mason**

Regards

rbo

Comment: I re-checked and loaded a mason file into Komodo (5.2) and it only supports (correct) syntax highlighting (of Perl parts and HTML-Parts) + minimal syntax checking on the Perl-Blocks. There's no *real* syntax check w/error display like in regular Perl-Files. Also, you have to direct Komodo (View -> "View as Language") to select Mason-display. So this wouldn't really fulfill your requirement (general syntax checking).

Answer (score 3):

We're adding multi-language syntax-checking to Komodo right now, and I'm adding Perl-specific
checking to Mason documents right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it supports anything special for Mason but have you tried [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/)?